# Square root (or Cholesky decomposition) of low rank symmetric matrix plus diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I would like to find the square root (or Cholesky decomposition) of
$$\Lambda = L_kL_k^T+D, $$
where $L_k$ is lower triangular with rank k (only first k columns have non-zero entries), D is positive diagonal.

$\Lambda$ is large, so I'm trying to massage the expression into something I can work with, but I have had no such luck. Ultimately, I just want to whiten Gaussian random variables according to this precision matrix, so if there's a better way to do that than factorizing $\Lambda$, I'm all ears.

Comment: I would start with the case in which $D = I$. However, even in this case, I don't see a good way to use the existing decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a series of $k$ [rank-1 updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Updating_the_decomposition). In particular, if $x_1,\dots,x_k$ denote the first $k$ columns of $L_k$, then we can write
$$
\Lambda = D + x_1x_1^T + \cdots + x_kx_k^T.
$$
To begin, note that $D$ has Cholesky decomposition $D = D^{1/2}D^{1/2}$.